# Redshift : How to join system tables on process id

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm looking to develop a query to detail connections, historic & present. With that, trying to join STL_CONNECTION_LOG + STV_SESSIONS, with the latter giving details of currently open sessions.

Starting with joining on process (pid), I was then hoping to use starttime to differentiate between the multiple reuses of a pid.

However, I was expecting the start time of a session to be after the starttime of its connection. Yet this is not the case..

It seems that sessions are started fractionally before the connection. Even though one of the "event"s in the connections log literally states "initiating session".

Wondered if anyone could explain how/why this logically works ?

I've also seen other folk including dB & user in the join - so does this mean that the same pid can be used concurrently within the cluster ?

Have looked for AWS docs to explain the mechanics but to no avail :(

Code to reveal the starttime discrepancies below...

```
select  
  c.recordtime cn_start, 
  c.event, 
  s.starttime ssn_start, 
  date_diff('microsec',c.recordtime,s.starttime) 
from   
  stl_connection_log c   
  left outer join   
  stv_sessions s   
  on c.pid = s.process 
where   
  --c.event='initiating session'   
  c.pid = 1073938862 
order by  
  recordtime desc limit 5;
```